# Is the expression of a switch statement evaluated once or for each case?

Tags: javascript

Is it a best practice to store the value of an expression in a variable, say

```
var category = fetchCategory();
switch(category) {
    case 'movie': ... break;
    case 'music': ... break;
    case 'book': ... break;
    default: ...
}
```

Versus:

```
switch(fetchCategory()) {
    case 'movie': ... break;
    case 'music': ... break;
    case 'book': ... break;
    default: ...
}
```

Any there any significant performance difference?

Comment: That depends, do you intend to use `category` only once, if so there's no performance gain to storing it ? The `switch` would probably call the function only once, and not on each case, in any modern optimized browser.

Comment: The switch expression is evaluated once, of course. The two are identical for all practical purposes.

Comment: You can easily test it yourself by putting e.g. an `alert()` into `fetchCategory`.

Answer (score 2):

The expression is evaluated once: [ECMAScript Language Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.11) says it is the result of evaluating the expression, so the function should only be called once.

I would prefer the second example, if a variable is not going to be used don't put it on the stack. It is more of a mental drain keeping track of it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, they are just the same.

this is the fiddle, as you can see, the function is called only once

http://jsfiddle.net/stratboy/q7ac2gqf/1/

```
function test(){ console.log('processing') }

switch(test()){
    case 1: console.log(1); break;
    case 2: console.log(2); break;
    default: console.log('default');
}
```